# Text label on top of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add multiple marker pins along with labels on top of an image.

Here is the jsfiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/at3wsepm/

I'm able to add the marker pins, but what is the best way to put a text label on top of the marker (from the pinid input) ?

I am adding the markers into a draggable object array

```
var pins = [];

$("#addPin").on("click", function(){
  var elem = $("<div/>").addClass("pin");
  $("#carea").append(elem);
    pins.push(new draggable(elem, updatePins));

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/at3wsepm/1/

Just add the text similarly how you create the pin. Let them be one item;

```
  var pintitle = $("#pinid").val();
  var elemstr= "<div>  <span  class='txt'>"+pintitle +"</span> </div>";
  var elem = $(elemstr).addClass("pin");
```

Notice the `span` that I added inside the `div`. Use CSS to adjust its location.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/at3wsepm/2/), css `Content` will work,

```
.pin:after{
 content: attr(content-after); // this will be set from jquery
}
$("#addPin").on("click", function(){
  var elem = $("<div/>");
  var id =$("#pinid").val(); // get text 
  elem.attr("id",id); 
  elem.addClass("pin");
  elem.attr('content-after',id); // set content-after id which css will catch from that name
  $("#carea").append(elem);
    pins.push(new draggable(elem, updatePins));

});
```

Hope helps,

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a label, and a text node, and set the text node's value to the value of input and append that label into the .pin div, i have altered your code, and it works like a charm

**HTML**

```
 <div id="carea" class="carea">
 <div id="pinsid" class="pinsid">

</div>
</div>

<div id="dsip"></div>

<input type="text" required="true" placeholder="Pin ID..." name="pinid" id="pinid">
<input type="button" value="Add Pin" id="addPin" >
```

**CSS**

```
#carea {

    background: #19d223;
    position: relative;
     width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.pin {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image:url('https://i.downloadatoz.com/download/icon2/5/f/9/ca21cf4a9f7385a7d55b2efcf2b8c0d3.jpg');
    cursor: move;
}

.pin label{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

**JS**

```
(function ($) {

  var draggable = function(element, updateFunc){
    this.position = {x : 0, y : 0};
    this.element = element;
    var _this = this;
    $(_this.element).draggable({

        stop: function() {

            _this.position.x = _this.element.position().left;
            _this.position.y = _this.element.position().top;
            updateFunc();
          }
    });
    }
  window.draggable = draggable;
}(window.jQuery));



var pins = [];

$("#addPin").on("click", function(){
  var elem = $("<div/>").addClass("pin");
  var label = document.createElement("label");  
   var detailt = document.createTextNode( $('input#pinid').val() );
   label.appendChild( detailt );
  elem.append(label);
  $("#carea").append(elem);

    pins.push(new draggable(elem, updatePins));

});
function updatePins(){
  $("#pinslist ul").empty();
  for(var p in pins){
     var pin = pins[p];

  }
}
//var dd = new draggable(null);
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rp0qdskL/3/) to it